# Delete multiple users by meta value - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to delete multiple users 1-100-1000, if they have specific value for metakey, which is MySQL datetime and it is less than other specific time, for the example - current time - 12 hours

I know I can select them in this way:

```
        $user = get_users(
            array(
                    'meta_key' => 'date_time_key',
                    'meta_value' => current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

            )
        );
```

, which will select all users that that key is equal to current time.

How to delete multiple users with one query (not selecting and then deleting with `wp_delete_user`) ?